# alert wrong with jquery value of password

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why the following script produce wrong JavaScript alert?

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
        $('#cpassword').change(function() {
     var pass=$('#password').val;
     alert(pass);
      var cpass=$('#cpassword').val;
      alert(cpass);
    });

    </script>
```

I have two password type where i get there value and compare to notify user on the right hand of text box but error is there. Help me out! How to get the value!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery uses the `.val()` **function** to get the value of the (first) element in a jQuery object. You're attempting to access the `val` **property** of that object. Try the following (note the `()` to indicate you're calling a function, not accessing a property):

```
$('#cpassword').change(function() {
    var pass = $('#password').val();
    alert(pass);
    var cpass = $('#cpassword').val();
    alert(cpass);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should call the `.val()` function to retrieve the input value. `.val` without `()` is the function declaration.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $('#cpassword').change(function() {
        var pass=$('#password').val();
        alert(pass);
        var cpass=$('#cpassword').val();
        alert(cpass);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`val()` is an function, so it has to be called as `element.val()`.

Use the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 2):

If you run that code in javascript console, you shall see that `$('#cpassword').val` is the function instance itself. Whilst `$('#cpassword').val()` is the result of that function run/

So, the solution - just add braces near `.val()` function call:

```
alert($('#cpassword').val());
```